# iPhone Memory Leak JSON Library

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management, sdk, memory-leaks

I'm getting an instruments Memory Leak with this iPhone 3.0 SDK code.

I'm using the JSON from http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Here is my code:

```
// .h
@property (nontatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *tweets;


// .m
import" JSON.h"
@synthesize tweets;
...
    tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com"];
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSArray *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
    NSArray *data = [results valueForKey:@"stories"];

    for(NSDictionary *tweet in data) {
        TweetmemeData *tweetmeme = [[TweetmemeData alloc] initWithTweet:tweet];
        [tweets addObject:tweetmeme];
        [self debugDump:tweetmeme];
        [tweetmeme release];
    }
    [results release];

    return tweets;
```

If possible, please explain more about this form of memory management. I'm very familiar with retain/release but obviously am having trouble implementing it :)

Thanks!

Comment: Notice that I am NOT releasing the NSArray *data ... if I do I get a lockup. Also, if I RETAIN results it seems to help... thanks in advance

Comment: According to convention, since [jsonString JSONValue] does not contain the words "alloc", "new", or "copy", it presumably returns an autoreleased pointer, which means you shouldn't have to release the "results" array.  The same goes for the "data" NSArray.

Comment: Seems that 'tweets' should perhaps be autoreleased - you're alloc/initing it and then returning it at the end of the method.

Also, if 'tweets' is a property, you probably want to use self.tweets instead of tweets so that when it is init'd, it is retained per the property declaration.

Without all the code, hard to say but from what you've shown, things seem unbalanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that many leaks that will come up in the simulator don't happen at all on the hardware. Are you using the simulator or testing it on the phone?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the info. I am using the Simulator.. will check the device.

Notice that I am NOT releasing the NSArray *data ... if I do I get a lockup. Also, if I RETAIN results it seems to help...

thanks in advance

Comment: You should read up on Memory Management, here's Apple's official guide: http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html  and here is another pretty good article I found: http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/